# Добавить смайлы в Delphi в поле RichEdit, либо же Memo

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!) Вот появился небольшой вопрос. Как эти самые смайлы в `Delphi` добавить? В поле `RichEdit`, либо же `Memo`. Также, можно сторонние компоненты. Делаю небольшой чат, единственное вот осталось. Искал в гугле, он мне не помог.
Как сделать это, даже представления пока - что не имею.`введите код здесь`

Comment: P.S. ты с Майкопа или ник такой просто? ))

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал тебе для этих целей - **RxRichEdit** из библиотеки **RxLib**, или же **JvRichEdit** из библиотеки **JVCL**, там куча возможностей и прочих плюшек + идут с примерами.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего - label + image. :) И все это в panel, пользуясь тем, что редактировать окно чата нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант - использовать TWebBrowser, там и смайлы и отображение в любом виде нарисовать будет проще.